# Temple of the Ancients - Can I return?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

In Final Fantasy VII I'm currently in the temple of the ancients. While exploring I've seen various items that I haven't managed to pick them up while going through and was wondering I can return later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The Temple of Ancients is inaccessible after you complete it.